# Game mechanics based on similar game

Tags: game-mechanics, copyright

I want to make an iOs game that is based on an online flash game. There will be quite some differences, but the game mechanics will be extremely similar. Do I have to worry about getting sued by the company that made the flash game??? I think not , after all DOOM is similar to Quake but they didn't get sued as far as I know. 
  Has anybody had any similar problems? (getting sued for making a game with very similar game mechanics)

Comment: Question aside, Doom and Quake were both created by idSoftware ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. Just don't use the names that are a TM and you are good.

Comment: There is a problem here ... It's a quizz game, get a question with 4 possible answers ,select one , You get the general idea ... I'm going to have helper options ... How do I change the name of well know options like 50:50 (to leave only 2 possible answers) ... The users may not appreciate something like that going under a different name....

Comment: Well, I suppose things like "call someone" or "50:50" are not special enough to be copyrighted, especially since that flash game probably got that from Who Wants To Be A Millionaire or a similar show in the first place, which in turn probably didn't invent it either. But I'm not a lawyer, so don't take that for granted.

To be on the safe side, just rename it ("strike two wrong answers", "phone a pal" or something) to names that haven't been used or, if you don't want to do that, create fitting icons, conveying clearly what each option is.

Comment: That's what I thought too . They use 50:50 also, and I don't think they paid anybody (like the makers of Who Wants To Be A Millionaire) for the right to use that name ...

Comment: As I said - IANAL, so none of what I say is legal advice. To be abolutely sure, you'd have to talk to a lawyer, preferrably one that specialises in copyright and or trademarks.

EDIT: Damn, hit Enter too soon. Anyway, my gut feeling would be that for example 50:50 is not only used in several quiz shows and game, but also a common figure of speech, so I can't imagine it being copyrighted. But look out for which fonts you use, don't design UI too similar, or something along those lines. These are little things that could potentially get you in trouble, if the wrong dude notices it.

Comment: Fifty:Fifty. There you go. No seriously, nobody is going to care about that.

Comment: Thanks guys ... but why did I get a -1 on the question

Comment: @user1028028 Because the question had already been asked. People will -1 when the question shows no research effort.